# Probabilty that the sum of a selection of $4$ digits 0 through $9$ will equal 20

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question is as follows:

Four selections of single digits are made at random with replacement from the $10$ digits $0$  through $9$.

Find the probability that the sum of the selected digits will equal $20$.

Having a lot of difficulty with this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the polynomial
$$p(x):=(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^9)^4\ .$$
If we expand $p$ distributively then each selection of four digits in $[0..9]$ produces a term with coefficient $1$ in this expansion, and the exponent of that term is equal to the sum of the selected digits. It follows that the number $N$ of "good" selections is the  coefficient of $x^{20}$ in this expansion, after terms have been collected.

We may rewrite $p$ as
$$p(x)=\left({1-x^{10}\over 1-x}\right)^4=(1-4x^{10}+6x^{20}-\ldots)\sum_{k=0}^\infty{-4\choose k}(-x)^k\ .$$
Collecting terms we then obtain
$$N={23\choose 20}-4{13\choose 10}+6=633\ .$$
The probability $P$ in question  is therefore given by
$$P={633\over 10^4}=6.33\%\ .$$

Comment: Should not it be $(-x)^k$ in the infinite sum?

Comment: Could you please explain why the number of good selections is the coefficient of $x^{20}$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Student: See my edit.